# Babel transform import statements

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC solution with my front-end scripts in TypeScript. I am trying to use webpack and babel with ts-loader so I can develop with es2016 but have babel transform to es5 and be able to run and debug in IE from Visual Studio. However I find that the output js is not transformed as I expect. For example the following statements in my ts appear in my resulting js, which are not es5:

```
import * as moment from 'moment'; 
import { classes } from './order';
```

Here is my config:

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'Scripts'),
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './pos.ts'],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'Scripts'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader'],
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
        }]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": [ "dom", "es2015", "es2016" ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts",
    "Scripts/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "foo",
  "readme": "README.md",
  "description": "foo",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-bower": "^0.0.13",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.4.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.3.0",
    "gulp-rimraf": "^0.2.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.6.3",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.3.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.46",
    "@types/bootstrap-touchspin": "",
    "@types/maskedinput": "",
    "@types/bootstrap-select": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline"
  }
}
```

Webpack appears to be running successfully in that there are no errors and js is created from my ts.  I think that Babel is being invoked because if I put in an invalid preset I get an error. However as noted above it seems like Babel is not transforming to es5. I have tried other presets like env and 2016.  What am I missing?

Comment: Where do you expect the transformed files? Babel is only applied from webpack and all that happens in memory, there is no output file. Also webpack handles ES modules and you should leave them to webpack instead of transpiling them.

Comment: The transformed file is specified by my webpack config - [name].js

Comment: I'm pretty new to both Webpack and Babel so I could be missing something fundamental because I thought Babel was required to be able to develop in ES6/2015+ and still support older browsers.

Comment: The webpack output (the bundle) does not contain any import statements, they are all using a webpack specific module loading (which works in every browser). Babel would be needed for newer features, but you can also configure TypeScript to transform to ES5 (`"target": "es5"`). Either way you should leave ES modules (do not transpile them to `require`) because it enables webpack features like [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

Comment: In that case webpack must not be doing what I think, because it does deposit a js file (the bundle) in the output path, which still contains the original import statements from my TypeScript, and of course IE chokes on those statements.  I have also tried using TypeScript `"target": "es5"` and that also leaves import statements which IE cannot comprehend.

Comment: Are you sure that you're including the output bundle, which should be `Scripts/main.js` and not the original files? It's best to create a specific directory for the webpack output (e.g. `dist/`), it makes it easier for version control, deployment and avoids confusion of using the wrong file.

Comment: You are correct, there was some monkey business going on with my output paths. I found the webpack-ed version that had the webpack module handlers in it.  Still Babel was not doing what it should have done, and was leaving other non-es5 keywords in place such as "Class". I ended up removing Babel and going with just TypeScript `"target": "es5"` + webpack. If you can make your comment into an answer I'll mark it as such since it got me going in the right direction. I'll start a separate issue about sourcemaps and debugging.